# Old recipe conversions

Tags: conversion

My old recipe for buckeyes (cookies) calls for one package of crackers. That was when the box was a pound box. Does anyone know the conversion since the box is now less weight and less crackers?

Comment: Welcome, Diane! How much is in a box now? It's difficult for us to help you with conversions if we don't know what you're starting with.

Comment: Buy enough boxes to get 1 pound of crackers, done?

Answer (score 3):

Just divide one pound (16 ounces) by the weight of the box you have now. For example, if the new box is 14.4 ounces (seems to be a common size for graham crackers), then you need 16/14.4 = 1.11 boxes.

You might find Google helpful for this kind of thing: you can search for [1 pounds / 14.4 ounces](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%20pounds%20/%2010%20ounces) and get an answer.

In the end you're probably best off just weighing, though: get enough boxes to have more than a pound, then weigh out a pound.

Or... if you're in exactly this situation, with a 14.4 ounce box that contains 3 packages of 9 crackers each, then that 0.11 of a box is an extra three crackers (27 * 16 / 14.4 = 30).